# Why Reachability reports wrong status

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I use [NetworkReachabilityManager](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift) class from Alamofire 4.3 to check for connection after request fails with next error:

`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."`

I turn on Airplane mode on my iPhone, start listening to reachability notifications when request fails. Then I turn off Airplane mode and NetworkReachabilityManager reports 4 status changes in next order: reachable (ethernetOrWiFi), not reachable, reachable (ethernetOrWiFi), not reachable. I wonder why it's happening. Also it doesn't report status change when I turn on Airplane mode again (perhaps because it compares last status with new one and they are same).

Does anybody know why Reachability report wrong status?

**Edit 1:**

Code sample:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON { [weak self] response in
            guard  let `self` = self else { return }
            guard response.result.isFailure else { completion(response); return}
            print (response.debugDescription)
            let error = response.error as! NSError
            guard error.code == -1009 else { completion(response); return}
            if self.reachabilityManager == nil {
                self.reachabilityManager = APNetworkReachabilityManager(host: self.baseURL)
                self.reachabilityManager?.listener = { status in
                    if self.reachabilityManager!.isReachable {

                    }
                }
                self.reachabilityManager?.startListening()
            }
    }
```

Comment: please provide code sample

Comment: and check your device 4G network connection . make sure that is turn on

Comment: added code sample, 4G & WiFi is on

Comment: turn on and turn off doing   repeatedly . or trying another network if possible . error represent net connection not available in the device

Comment: I know what that error represents. If you read my description, it's happening by intention, when I switch on Airplane mode. My network works correctly. Obviously a reason is not in it.

Comment: UIRequiresPersistentWifi key to your Info.plist and set it to YES

Comment: My app doesn't require persistent WiFi connection, it can work over cellular network, so why should I enable that key?